# how to set UserControl Screen at center of page in wpf

Tags: wpf

i need to keep usercontrol page at center location of page 
to keep window form at center thr is option in property WindowStartuplocation center
but for usercontrol i m not getting

Answer (score 0):

your UserControl has to be in an other control (Window, Grid, Canvas, etc...), so set the postion of this control at center location and you will be good !

Example :

```
 <Canvas>
       <YourUserControl Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left ="400"></YourUserControl>
 </Canvas>
```